# How to get the newest value of column E and display the value in A1?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need help to make Google spreadsheet like this.

You can input values in column E, and the value of the newest input is displayed in A1.

[image]

I tried the below code, but it didn't work.

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("E:E");
  var inputinE = range;
  var colA = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
  colA = inputinE.getValues();
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details like how are you running the script, if you get an error message add it textually and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: It is unclear why you would need a script to do this when a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula can do the same. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell `A1`:

`=+sort(E2:E, E2:E <> "", false, row(E2:E), false)`